# What is the 'largest' space of integrable functions which is also a Hilbert space?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

It is well known that $L^2(X,\mu)$, the set of functions $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ such that $\int_X |f|^2 \text{d} \mu < \infty$, is a Hilbert space. Is there a Hilbert space $H$ such that $L^2(X,\mu)\subset H$? In other words, are there larger classes of integrable functions which form a hilbert space?

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $V$ be the orthogonal complement of $L^2(X,\mu)$ in $H$ and let $f$ be a function in $V$.

Then, $\int fg d \mu =0$ for all $g$ in $L^2(X,\mu)$. This condition easily implies that $f$ is identically zero.

Comment: You are assuming $H \subseteq L^{2}(X,\mu)$ in your argument, aren't you?

Comment: @T.A.E.: No. I am assuming that $H \subseteq L^\infty(X,\mu)$

Comment: And you are assuming $\int fg\,d\mu$ makes sense for all $g \in L^{2}(X,\mu)$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Actually I was thinking more of just characteristic functions. The integral need not make sense for all $g$, (unless $\mu$ is a finite measure.)

Comment: Then there is the second point that you are assuming functions $f$, and assuming those functions are measurable.

Comment: @T.A.E.: As they belong to $H$ which by OP's question is a subset of $L^\infty$.

Comment: Okay, I see how you are interpreting. Thanks.